# I want to add customized validation for the date time

Tags: php, jquery, datetime

In PHP I have used below code to get the time of US.

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
$dateTimeZoneLA = new DateTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles");
$dateTimeLA = new DateTime("now", $dateTimeZoneLA);
```

Now I need to add validation of datetime using jQUery but how can I match the US time with the calender time. time using jQUery. Below is the code I have used in jQuery. But it did not workk acc. to US time.

```
var starttime = $('#dateTime').val();
var present = new Date(now);
var firstDate = new Date(starttime);  
if(present.getTime() > firstDate.getTime()){
    $('#dateTime').after('`<ul class="errors"><li>Sorry, but you cannot add past date.</li></ul>`');

}
```

Comment: Where are you getting the value of `now` in your JavaScript?

Comment: If your javascript's now is in the browsers timezone, it will fail. You need to set the timezone explicitly in javascript to match the server timezone

Comment: The now() method returns the milliseconds elapsed since 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC up until now as a Number.

Because now is a static method of Date.
var present returns me the present time